# 3D Vector Field Plot

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am creating an Electromagnetic field simulator and I am using Qt3D to plot cuboids.The output should be the same input cuboid but with different color distribution indicating the magnetic field at each point but I can't figure how to plot it this way with various colors.

Input (2 intersecting cuboids):

[image]

Output should be similar to this:

[image]